# Infinite CCLayer Background

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to make an infinite Background in Cocos2D?

Suppose you have a 2d game with a small spaceship, the layer is moved when the ship travels in any direction. Having a static star background leaves will sooner or later be off-screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tile the background image.
Here is a sample code

```
 CCSprite * bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pattern11.jpg" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 256, 256)];
    [bg setPosition:ccp(0, 0)];
    ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
    [bg.texture setTexParameters:&params];
    [self addChild:bg z:0];
```

Make sure that the tiles are in this format: 256x256 or 128x128

Comment: Hi, well, this does not make the background infinite, but bound to the rect 0,0,256,256 ...

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Not sure if there is an built in way to do it. I have created an iPhone game with infinite background and the trick that I use is two copies of same image appended one after another as you move forward. But my code is in Objective C...

Comment: I guess I will have to do this as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCParallaxNode.

Here's a link to the CCParallaxNode Class Reference:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/1.0.0/interface_c_c_parallax_node.html

And here's a great tutorial that shows how to use it:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game

Comment: Unfortunately it is a) not infinite b) not working to scroll in any direction.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Off the top of my head, if you mean: in any direction, never repeating, all I can think of is particles that flow in the direction you're traveling creating the illusion of movement. If just left to right, the parallax node can be easily reversed, but obviously you are confined to x number of images, which I assume that is not what you want.